# Repeat a diagonal logo to make a seamless background image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My question is on the best way to produce a tileable background image from a simple text logo.

The logo is to be rotated so it is at an angle and then a small tileable image is to be made from it. An example result is [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7lx3.gif) used by the FT Alphaville twitter page. Although their image is not tiled - it is just big enough to fill most screens - the concepts required to rotate the text and repeat it are the same.

Any links to useful tutorials would also be appreciated as I understand this is not that straightforward a question and some maths is involved.